# Is it safe to use css class in the loop as an array key which is related to database value?

Tags: database, security

I am printing div blocks in the loop, using associative array. I want to use keys of such arrays as a css class for each div. The thing is those keys are directly connected to database fields. Is it safe to do so? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. You are retrieving keys from a database, and want to use these as CSS class names? Are these classes statically defined in your style sheet? How are you validating that the class is defined before writing it to the database? Or maybe I'm missing the point.

Comment: not really, maybe I have asked it unclearly. I gather some values from fields in database, those field are keys of an associative array. While printing div blocks I use those keys as class names for blocks. I hope I made it clear. Classes are not defined in stylesheet. I need to use them as a selector for jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problems in that, but try to never use database field's name in JS or HTML code. I think you can concatenate them with a prefix or change the order of the chars, so you can play around with String functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using those CSS classes to create a query then yes.  For example if you have the HTML below:

```
<div class="someValue">test</div>
```

And you use this HTML to create a SQL Query like this:

```
DELETE someValue
```

or:

```
SELECT someValue FROM myTable
```

Someone could easily change the value of `myTable` to something else.

If you are not creating a SQL Query from that value then the biggest issues is that people could potentially figure out your column names based on your HTML which isn't great but probably isn't a huge deal.